# Tbats function in R

Tags: r, forecasting

Could I ask you something for tbats? I have a daily multiseasonal data with frequencies(7,30.41,365) and I would like to forecast with tbats. The big problem I have is that my data is about only one year. So when I run tbats the results are not right.

How could I resolve this and for one year data to have forecast for example for next two months with right results. I think that when I have less than twice of the smaller frequency this function does not work. This is right?

Thank you for your time. It is very important my quastion because I can not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

for good forecast you should have at least 5 years of data. you have one year of data which is not sufficient to find trend and seasonality present in the data, it will not return you good forecast.

Even you applied forecast method like arima() or tbats() it will give you simple average value and you will get straight  line.

Its better you should try naive().